# How do you modify array parameter in swift

Tags: swift

I need to manipulate data inside a byte array using swift. The compiler will not permit the following:

```
var a:[UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5]
func tt(a:[UInt8]) {
    a[2]=10
}
tt(a:a)
```

The compiler complains:

```
Cannot assign through subscript: 'a' is a 'let' constant
```

What is the correct way to create functions that can modify large byte arrays. (They are very large)

I am aware there are Unsafe pointer options, but I am trying various types of unsafe pointer parameters and none of them seem to work or they report even more obscure compiler errors, so I thought I would ask here. i.e.

```
func tt(a:UnsafePointer<[UInt8]>) {
    a[2]=a[3]
}


func tt(a:UnsafeMutablePointer<[UInt8]>) {
    a[2]=a[3]
}
```

Comment: `func tt(b:[UInt8]) { b[2]=10 }`, just renaming the parameter to avoid confusion. The parameter is `b` is a `let` by default, since it's a parameter. You might want an `inout`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll google what inout is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tt(a:[UInt8]) {
    a[2]=10
}
```

In above function, the function parameter `a` is a `let` constant, you can't change it inside the function.

You need to use `inout` parameter to be able to modify this.

```
var a: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5]
func tt(a: inout [UInt8]) {
    a[2] = 10
}
tt(a: &a)
```

Comment: I didnt know enough about swift to add this additional question. Willl this avoid memory copies of the arrays?   (Im about to throw this in a loop that will be called 100 million times or so, I dont want to create performance or memory issues on the iPhone.

Comment: The `inout` won't cause copies of this array to be created on mutation. Notice the special syntax `&`, it works in a similar way as in call by reference.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each value passed inside a function parameter is a constant, to be able to mutate it you need to sign it as inout

```
func tt(a: inout [UInt8]){
   a[2]=10
}
```